# "Is there a way to create a permutation or product of list of tuples in Python?"

Tags: python-3.x, product, permutation

```
lis=[
    (1, 7), (1, 2), (1, 4), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 4), (2, 1), (2, 7), (2, 4), (4, 
    1), (4, 7), (4, 2)
]
```

Suppose I have the above list of tuples. I want to create all possible list of tuples such as `[(1,7,1,2),(1,2,1,4) ...]`. Each tuple in the resultant list must be a permutation of 2 tuples in the list and the resultant list must contain all such tuples.

`list(permutations(lis,4))` gives result: `[((1, 7), (1, 2), (1, 4), (7, 1)), ((1, 7), (1, 2), (1, 4), (7, 2))...]`. It is forming a tuples of 4 tuples. But I want the inner tuples to be unpacked and consisting of 4 elements of 2 tuples rather than tuples of tuples.

Comment: `[(x + y) for x in ls for y in lis if x != y]` assuming there are no duplicate tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of accomplishing it:

```
[a + b for a, b in permutations(lis, 2)]
```